# Using Joins and Views in SQL

Tags: sqlite

I essentially have 4 tables, but not all the tables have common fields

- Table 1 has A
- Table 2 has A and B
- Table 3 has B and C
- Table 4 has C

so when I tried to join them all, it doesn't work because

> SQLITE_ERROR: cannot join using column C - column not present in
>   all tables

Which I understand, not all the table share the same columns.
I tried creating a view (TABLE_ABC) using "table1, table2, and table3", then tried doing a join to that view

> Join TABLE_ABC using (C)

but I get the same SQLITE Error.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to join all 4 tables even though they all do not share a column? Do I just need to create a 5th table using "table1, table2, and table3" and connect 4 to that?
2. Can you do a join to a view?

Comment: So after running test, I realize you can to a JOIN to a custom VIEW after several test. I'm still curious, what would the best way to join the 4 tables otherwise.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the `using` syntax when doing joins (to avoid issues like this). Just use standard join syntax, e.g. `... from tablea join tableb on tableb.columna = tablea.columna`.

Comment: haha, our teachers taught us the opposite oddly enough, but I think i will go back to using the more specific syntax. it makes more sense to me using that as well

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fe488/1). Please provide a [mcve].